# What should be Assert for below code, tried for assertTrue,assertFalse,assertNull and assertNotNull

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, testng

I have written below code to verify web table data headers and value of rows and columns but when I am adding different assertion for it, its not working and throwing compilation error. Can any one help me on this, my most of the test cases depend on this.

I have to use this code to put in assertion: Tried with below assertion

Assert.assertNotNull(HandleWebTable.printAllHeaderOfWebTable());

**Error message:** Assert.assertNotNull(HandleWebTable.printAllHeaderOfWebTable( ) is not applicable for the argument void --> same message is coming for all assertion.

```
package com.deere.gmsr.utility;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

import com.deere.gmsr.driver.Driver;

public class HandleWebTable {

    private static WebDriver driver;

    public HandleWebTable(){
        super();
    }

    public static void printAllHeaderOfWebTable() {

    List<WebElement> allHeaderTable=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='panel history-panel panel panel-default']"));

    int allHeaderSize=allHeaderTable.size();

    ListIterator<WebElement> tr=allHeaderTable.listIterator();

    System.out.println("Traverse in forwrd direction");

    while(tr.hasNext()) {

        System.out.println("index" + tr.nextIndex() + "value" + tr.next());
    }

    List<WebElement> allHeaderTable1=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='panel history-panel panel panel-default']"));

    int allHeaderSize1=allHeaderTable1.size();


    List<WebElement> allRows=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[section/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/table/thead/tr/th[1]]"));

    for(WebElement allRowsName:allRows) {
        System.out.println(allRowsName.getText());

    }


}


}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't have any assertion. Could you share the original code, with the assertions and the error message / stacktrace?

Comment: I have to use this code to put in assertion: Assert.assertNotNull(HandleWebTable.printAllHeaderOfWebTable());  message:  Assert.assertNotNull(HandleWebTable.printAllHeaderOfWebTable(
 ) is not applicable for the argument void --> same message is coming for all assertion.
...
...

Comment: Please, edit your question with this code - the comment section is pretty unreadable for this kind of text.

Comment: I have updated the code, Please have a look and let me know what should be the right approach to assert web table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `printAllHeaderOfWebTable` returns nothing (*void*).

In Java, it doesn't mean that it returns *null*.

What you can do it to return the list of rows and check if there are any row:

```
public static List<WebElement> printAllHeaderOfWebTable() {
   /// ...
   return allRows;
}
// It will pass if the list is not empty
Assert.assertFalse(HandleWebTable.printAllHeaderOfWebTable().isEmpty());
```